# Angular2 AoT 404 when loading compiled scripts

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, aot

I'm working on an Angular2 *(latest version)* project within Visual Studio 2015 Community environment. I have set the settings for the AoT and I'm outputting to `/aot` folder.

When I run the project, I get the following error in my browser:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:15609/aot/app/app.module.ngfactory

localhost/:28 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:15609/aot/app/app.module.ngfactory
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:15609/aot/app/app.module.ngfactory
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:15609/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:647:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:15609/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:37)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:15609/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:136:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:15609/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:304:33)
    Error loading http://localhost:15609/aot/app/app.module.ngfactory as "../aot/app/app.module.ngfactory" from http://localhost:15609/app/main.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:15609/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:647:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:15609/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:37)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:15609/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:136:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:15609/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:304:33)
    Error loading http://localhost:15609/aot/app/app.module.ngfactory as "../aot/app/app.module.ngfactory" from http://localhost:15609/app/main.js(anonymous function) @ localhost/:28
```

I can locate the file inside a folder structure of the application. It is there, and not empty.

My main.ts file looks like this:

```
import {platformBrowser} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../aot/app/app.module.ngfactory';

platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

If needed I can provide other needed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your error log error your `main.ts` and `app.module.ngfactory` file is in `app` folder so your include path in `main.ts` should be `import { AppModuleNgFactory } from 'app.module.ngfactory';`.

I think you are getting error because of your relative path mismatch after your aot compilation.

Comment: Actually, the `../aot/app/app.module.ngfactory` module does get recognized. But for some reason is not imported as it should. 

What I did was just compile into a root folder and accessed it like this: `./app/app.module.ngfactory`. I guess the compiler does not like when going up on the folder tree. 

Thanks for the hint tho!